# new dags not shown on docker airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

**Problem:** new dags not shown on docker airflow, no error when running `airflow dags list-import-errors`

**Docker image:** [official airflow image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow)

**Dags path** inside `docker-compose.yaml` (this is the default path):

```
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
```

I put the dag file inside the `dags` folder on the main directory, as shown below:
[image]

However, the `dags` is still not shown on both `webserver UI` and `airflow dags list`. Running `airflow dags list-import-errors` also yield no result.

When I open the docker terminal, I can see my dag inside the dags folder via `ls` command. I also tried to make the owner root by using `chown`, but both of my dag still not shown up on the list.

The airflow run successfully (via `docker compose`) as I can see example dags, but not my own dags.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try a few things:

- rename files to sth like `gcp_dag.py` and `python_dag.py`
- ensure `import airflow` is present in each file
- ensure you create `DAG` object in each file
- add `__init__.py` (empty) file to dags folder

It would be also helpful to see contents of at least one of those files.

Comment: *"ensure you create `DAG` object in each file"* - and make sure it is available via `globals()`.  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html?highlight=globals#loading-dags

Answer (score 1):

1. do not name your python DAGs test_* that probably does not matter but this is usually a convention for unit tests
2. make sure there is a DAG word in your dags (or change https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-discovery-safe-mode to False)  - the DAGs can be ignored if they do not contain "DAG" or "airflow"
3. Exec into your scheduler container and check if it can see and read the DAGs and whether the env vars are properly set `airflow info` run in your scheduler container (providing that it is run with the same env as the running scheduler) should show all the configuration
4. Check if your scheduler is runnning
5. look at the logs of the scheduler and see if it is scanning the right folders - enabling DEBUG log might be helpful https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#logging-level
6. see if you can see the dags with `airflow dags` sub commands

Answer (score 1):

It might also be a problem with permissions. Check what user is assigned to the DAG files or better try to view the files from inside the container, like this:

```
docker exec -it <container> bash
cat /opt/airflow/dags/test_gcp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using MacOS and my docker application (`Docker desktop`) Did not have permission to read DAG files.

So if you are using Mac, make sure your Docker app (whether it is `Docker desktop`, `Rancher` or etc) has access to the files where your DAGs are located. By default these Apps do not have permission over your files and you have to go to `System preferences > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders` and give access to your docker app to read the files on your system.

Also one way to check if this is really the problem is to open a shell session in the container that you are running your airflow on, so use `docker exec -it -u root <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash` and try to run `ls -a dags/` in the shell session. If the permission issue mentioned above is the case, you will see an error much like `Operation not permitted`